# invoking asp.net controller action from angularjs-ui $modal templateUrl

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

On angularjs-ui `$modal.open()` with template URL set to asp.net mvc's controller action, modal popup opens with html content from my mvc view. below is the code for it.

```
 $scope.createNewWizardLine = function () 
{
        var jobLineRecIds = $scope.selectedLineIds.split(",");
        $scope.wizardLineRecId = jobLineRecIds[0];
        if ($scope.wizardLineRecId) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/job/jobWizardLineModal/' + $scope.wizardLineRecId,
                scope: $scope
            });
        }
        else {
            log("Please select job line");
        }
    }
```

The controller action is invoked only the very first time, on subsequent call to **createNewWizardLine()** my asp.net's mvc controller action doesn't invoke.

The ***$modal* is loading the cached content. But i want it to load from the action everytime i make a call to **createNewWizardLine()**

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing it and I'm stuck. If you solve it, please answer your own question to help others like me. :)

Comment: @Kiwanax, sorry for the damn late response, i tried a workaround.
i just passed dummy querystring which refreshes on every call